# List all files that are less than 1024 bytes in size and have names ending in *zip

Tags: linux, command-line

As the title states, how would I go about piping this command? I know how to do each separately, but no clue on how to combine them into one command.

```
find . -type f -size -1024c -ls | ls -l *zip
```

give me all files ending in zip but some are greater than 1024 bytes

Comment: So how would you do each separately?

Comment: just edited my post to show

Comment: Look in the `find` man page for a `-name` operator.

Comment: so would I pipe with another find or use -name with the first command?

Comment: @Drew The latter: `find . -type f -name '*.zip' -size -1024c -ls`. If you want to execute a command on the "found" file, see the `-exec` option of `find`. More complex cases are handled by piping the output name to `xargs {command}` (in which case the `-print0` option of find and `-0` option of `xargs` are recommended).

Comment: ah, I wasn't using the single quotes around zip. also found that I could pipe with `grep '*zip'`

Comment: It's worth noticing your original pipe makes no sense because `ls` discards its standard input. Compare `echo "mumbo jumbo" | ls /`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-name` option in `find`

```
find . -type f -name '*zip' -size -1024c -ls
```

It is usually a good idea to quote the pattern so that it is resolved by 'find' and not by the shell  (otherwise, if you have a .zip if your current directory the shell will replace the pattern by that name).

If you want to execute a command on the "found" file, see the `-exec` option of find. More complex cases are handled by piping the output names to `xargs {command}` (in which case the `-print0` option of find and `-0` option of `xargs` are recommended).

Answer (score 1):

As G-Man mentioned in a comment: use `-name`:

```
find . -type f -size -1024c -name '*zip' -ls
```